# Obfuscation option in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, obfuscation

I didn't find obfuscation option in Eclipse IDE When i searched in

Windows --> Preferences -->Android(In side) --> **obfuscation(DexGuard)**

I didn't find Obfuscation option in my IDE.

How to find? Is there any Plugin requried?? if yes which one??

Thanks,

Comment: Use android studio

Comment: First release App in Eclipse... so we need to build in Eclipse only... I need for Eclipse solution..

Comment: Where did you find this option documented?

Comment: i got solution , i posted in answer section...@nitind , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution of above question,

**OBFUSCATION:**

1- Copy the plugin.jar from DexGuard's eclipse directory to the dropins directory of your Eclipse install

2- Then u go to, Windows --> Preferences -->Android(In side) --> obfuscation(DexGuard)--> Enable Obfuscation

3- Typically dexguard does the process automatically but if you need any specific proguarding tasks. Write it into the dexguard-project.txt  file.